# npm Windows cmd syntax for passing environment variables (not recognized as internal or external command)

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, cmd

What is the syntax for writing this command line command on Windows cmd.

```
MY_ENV_VAR=2 npm run my_script
```

or

```
MY_VAR1=100 MY_VAR2=300 npm run my_script
```

Basically I am trying to set the environment variables on my script.

Inside my index.js, for example, I have:

```
const MY_VAR1 = process.env.MY_VAR1 || 200;
```

Every time I run this on Windows cmd, I get "MY_VAR1 not recognized as internal or external command".

I have looked everywhere on the internet - this syntax seems to work on Mac but not on Windows cmd.

Please tell me the equivalent on Windows.

Of course, running

```
npm run my_script
```

runs fine.

Comment: `MY_ENV_VAR=2 npm run my_script` is in Windows command prompt window `set "MY_ENV_VAR=2" & npm run my_script` and in a Windows batch file `set "MY_ENV_VAR=2" & call npm.cmd run my_script`. `MY_VAR1=100 MY_VAR2=300 npm run my_script` is in command prompt window `set "MY_VAR1=100" & set "MY_VAR2=300" & npm run my_script` and in a batch file is replaced again `npm` by `call npm.cmd`. See [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding one more option for Windows. You can set the environment variables using `set` as follows.

```
set MY_VAR1=543
```

Then you'll get the value of `MY_VAR1` in `process.env.MY_VAR1` by running the `npm run` command.

```
npm run my_script
```

Or you can write the above two lines into single one using `&&`.

```
set MY_VAR1=543 && npm run my_script
```

Answer (score 3):

The two options I've most seen are:

1. Use [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about). That will provide you with a shell where environment variables can be set the same was as on Linux. So `MY_ENV_VAR=2 npm run my_script` will work.
2. Use [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env). Then it's `cross-env MY_ENV_VAR=2 npm run my_script`.

Comment: Hey. cross-env did work, but the command you gave me results in "cross-env is not recognized as an internal or external command". So actually, the steps would be 1. npm i cross-env --save-dev. 2. in package.json script section, write: "build": "cross-env MY_ENV_VAR=2 nodemon ./app". 3. in command line write 'npm run build'.